# Interact with smartcontracct via web3.js: Uncaught TypeError: MyContract.at is not a function

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, dapp-development

I'm trying to interact with my smartcontract but get the error: Uncaught TypeError: MyContract.at is not a function

My Code:

```
var web3 = require('ethereum.js');
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider());

var MyContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"x","type":"uint256"}],"name":"set","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"retVal","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"}]);

var result = MyContract.at("MyContractAddress").get();
console.log(result);
```

When I request default Geth functionality I get a correct response:

```
var version = web3.version.api;
console.log(version);  "0.2.4"
```

Comment: `var web3 = require('ethereum.js');` are you sure that it shouldn't be `var web3 = require('web3.js');`

Answer (score 5):

You need to provide the address of your geth node to the HttpProvider constructor so your web3 client is connected to a node. Certain web3 functions like contract.at() only works if you are connected to a node. web3.version.api does not need ethereum connection to function.

```
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://geth-node-ip:8545'));
```

If you did set an address for the HttpProvider, then check that the IP and port # are correct. (i'm using 8545 as an example since that's the default RPC port)

Comment: I add the node, but still no result. Like my example above I can get the Geth version and I can also get the transactionCount of a specific address:     var number = web3.eth.getTransactionCount("MyAddress"); console.log(number);

Comment: I don't know how you're getting the web3 instance from your "ethereum.js" file, but if i get mine from the following, the rest of your code works for me (provided I have the geth IP and actual contract address filled in). `var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();`

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an instance of that contract [as described here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract). You correctly created the contract object (consider placing your ABI into a separate file) but then need to create an instance via

```
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(ABI);
var contractInstance = MyContract.at(address);
```

If you have not deployed your contract, you have to do that first (this will give you the `address` which you can re-use from then on:

```
var contractInstance = MyContract.new([contructorParam1] [, contructorParam2], {data: '0x12345...', from: myAccount, gas: 1000000});
```

I placed a more complete walk-through [on my github](https://github.com/SCBuergel/timeLock-smartContract).

Comment: I still have the same result; MyContract.at is not a function.   It has problems  with the ".at" part, I also tried with another contract. The contract works fine in Geth.

Comment: Did you run the code that I suggested in geth or in the browser? Please try in geth first. Also check `console.log(JSON.stringify(MyContract))`.

Comment: I try the code in my browser but it only works in Geth console. I have communication from my browser to my Geth node with;     var number = web3.eth.getTransactionCount("MyAddress"); console.log(number);  But with MyContract.at I get an error.   I use the simple storage contract as an example: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html

Comment: And I'm running my Geth node with: geth --unlock 0 --rpc --rpcport "8080".  I can also send eth_sendTransaction via RPC JSON, the problem is that I want to request and display my balance. I'm stuck at MyContract.at...

Comment: Please post the output of what I suggested above.

Comment: Also make sure you're running geth and she the browser on the very same machine. I think remote access is disabled by default.

Comment: In my browser i get 'undefined' with console.log(JSON.stringify(MyContract)). With Geth it works with myContract.get()

Comment: Here my abi code in Geth: {
  abi: [{
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}],
      name: "set",
      outputs: [],
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "get",
      outputs: [{...}],
      type: "function"
  }],
  address: "0x8a85848d503dfD8817157D90aA27220e3E4CFB67",
  transactionHash: null,
  allEvents: function(),
  get: function(),
  set: function()
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39947/discussion-between-jeroen-and-sebastian).

Comment: Jeroen, check your ABI is a JS array when passed to web3.eth.contract(ABI) and not stringified.  I've been stumped by this same contract.at(addr) for days but have just sorted it now.

Comment: Solved, it was an issue with my web3.js libraries. After a reinstall it works.